# Не могу добавить картинку с ютуба в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube

Вот такой код:

```
def get_info(event):
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.mp4'
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        name = link.get()
        info = ydl.extract_info(name, download=False)

    title['text'] = f'Title: {info["title"]}'
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"{info['thumbnails'][0]['url']}")
    image['image'] = img
```

И ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "f:\dev\py\All\ydl\main.py", line 22, in get_info
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"{info['thumbnails'][0]['url']}")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4063, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4008, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d09-P9R5BRE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBVsQeq63m24f4iO9ZnqGGOkCemTQ": no such file or directory
```

Почему он говорит что файл не найден, хотя он есть?

Comment: Скорее всего, `tk` умеет только открывать картинки с диска.

Comment: аэа я тут уже все таки смог решить. просто с рекьюстс открыл картинку, ну там её и с подушкой подсунул